# unresponsive drag and drop in pygobject

Tags: python, introspection, pygobject, gtk3

im trying to get drag and drop working well in pygobject, but it is slow and unresponsive, 90% of the time i have to wave the item i am dragging around before i can drop it successfully, can anyone see if i am doing it incorrectly or is this a bug with pygobject? here is my code

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk
import os

def got_data_cb(windowid, context, x, y, data, info, time):
# Got data.
tempArray = data.get_text().splitlines()
for i in tempArray:
    i = i.replace('file://','')
    print i
    windowid.get_model().append([i])
context.finish(True, False, time)

def drop_cb(windowid, context, x, y, time):
# Some data was dropped, get the data
windowid.drag_get_data(context, context.list_targets()[-1], time)
return True

def main():
win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('destroy', lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
win.set_default_size(450, 400)

amodel = Gtk.ListStore(str)
column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn()
title = Gtk.CellRendererText()
column.pack_start(title, True)
column.add_attribute(title, "text", 0)
atree = Gtk.TreeView(amodel)
atree.append_column(column)

builder = Gtk.Builder()
filename = os.path.join('', 'treeview.ui')
builder.add_from_file(filename)
abox = builder.get_object('treeview1')

atree.drag_dest_set(0, [], 0)
atree.connect('drag_motion', lambda v,w,x,y,z: True)
atree.connect('drag_drop', drop_cb)
atree.connect('drag_data_received', got_data_cb)

win.add(atree)
win.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gtk.main()

main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Because I haven't "treeview.ui" file, you referenced, I port the [drag'n'drop treeview example of pygtk.](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TreeViewDragAndDrop.html)

This might be also an example on how to convert old pygtk code to pygi. I only test this code with python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example treeviewdnd.py

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango, GObject

class TreeViewDnDExample:

    TARGETS = [
        ('MY_TREE_MODEL_ROW', Gtk.TargetFlags.SAME_WIDGET, 0),
        ('text/plain', 0, 1),
        ('TEXT', 0, 2),
        ('STRING', 0, 3),
        ]
    # close the window and quit
    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def clear_selected(self, button):
        selection = self.treeview.get_selection()
        model, iter = selection.get_selected()
        if iter:
            model.remove(iter)
        return

    def __init__(self):
        # Create a new window
        self.window = Gtk.Window()

        self.window.set_title("URL Cache")

        self.window.set_size_request(200, 200)

        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        self.hbox = Gtk.HButtonBox()
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.scrolledwindow, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False, True, 0)
        self.b0 = Gtk.Button('Clear All')
        self.b1 = Gtk.Button('Clear Selected')
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.b0, True, True, 0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.b1, True, True, 0)

        # create a liststore with one string column to use as the model
        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)

        # create the TreeView using liststore
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(self.liststore)

       # create a CellRenderer to render the data
        self.cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()

        # create the TreeViewColumns to display the data
        self.tvcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('URL', self.cell, text=0)

        # add columns to treeview
        self.treeview.append_column(self.tvcolumn)
        self.b0.connect_object('clicked', Gtk.ListStore.clear, self.liststore)
        self.b1.connect('clicked', self.clear_selected)
        # make treeview searchable
        self.treeview.set_search_column(0)

        # Allow sorting on the column
        self.tvcolumn.set_sort_column_id(0)

        # Allow enable drag and drop of rows including row move
        self.treeview.enable_model_drag_source( Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK,
                                                self.TARGETS,
                                                Gdk.DragAction.DEFAULT|
                                                Gdk.DragAction.MOVE)
        self.treeview.enable_model_drag_dest(self.TARGETS,
                                             Gdk.DragAction.DEFAULT)
        self.treeview.drag_dest_add_text_targets()
        self.treeview.drag_source_add_text_targets()

        self.treeview.connect("drag_data_get", self.drag_data_get_data)
        self.treeview.connect("drag_data_received",
                              self.drag_data_received_data)

        self.scrolledwindow.add(self.treeview)
        self.window.add(self.vbox)
        self.window.show_all()

    def drag_data_get_data(self, treeview, context, selection, target_id,
                           etime):
        treeselection = treeview.get_selection()
        model, iter = treeselection.get_selected()
        data = bytes(model.get_value(iter, 0), "utf-8")
        selection.set(selection.get_target(), 8, data)

    def drag_data_received_data(self, treeview, context, x, y, selection,
                                info, etime):
        model = treeview.get_model()
        data = selection.get_data().decode("utf-8")
        drop_info = treeview.get_dest_row_at_pos(x, y)
        if drop_info:
            path, position = drop_info
            iter = model.get_iter(path)
            if (position == Gtk.TreeViewDropPosition.BEFORE
                or position == Gtk.TreeViewDropPosition.BEFORE):
                model.insert_before(iter, [data])
            else:
                model.insert_after(iter, [data])
        else:
            model.append([data])
        if context.get_actions() == Gdk.DragAction.MOVE:
            context.finish(True, True, etime)
        return

def main():
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    treeviewdndex = TreeViewDnDExample()
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for me to get drag n drop working from another desktop app to my app, I had to add a drag_motion_callback to copy the data into the context:

```
Class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        #other stuff before here
        #Set up dragNdrop to add URIs to open draw
        self.connect("drag-motion", self.motion_cb)
        self.connect("drag-drop", self.drop_cb)
        self.connect("drag-data-received", self.got_data_cb)
        self.drag_dest_set(0, [], 0)

    def motion_cb(self, wid, context, x, y, time):
        Gdk.drag_status(context,Gdk.DragAction.COPY, time)
        # Returning True which means "I accept this data".
        return True

    def drop_cb(self, wid, context, x, y, time):
        wid.drag_get_data(context, context.list_targets()[-1], time)

    def got_data_cb(self, wid, context, x, y, data, info, time):
        #Need to do something here
        files=data.get_text().rstrip('\n').split('\n')
        for fn in files:
            fn= fn.split('file://',1)[-1]
            self.add_file(fn)
        self.place_items()
        print files
        context.finish(True, False, time)
```